# Python Psycopg Named Arguments

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having an issue wrt use of query parameters. When trying to include query parameters in my "GROUP BY" (limit/offest) clauses I get errors. Using the query parameters in the other parts of my query are fine though.

This works:

```
query = "SELECT id, name, age from some_table where age > %(age)s"
query_param = {"age": 42}
cur.execute(query, query_param)
```

This does not work:

```
query = "SELECT id, name, age from some_table where age > %(age)s order by %(column_name)s"
query_param = {"age": 42, "column_name": "name"}
cur.execute(query, query_param)
```

I get  `order by %(column_name) ': unsupported format character ' '`

docs: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: 1) `%(column_name)` is not  a correct named parameter, it should be `%(column_name)s`. 2) In this case it does not matter as you cannot use a parameter for a column name. 3) See [Sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for how to build dynamic SQL including identifiers e.g. column names.

Comment: Thanks, that was the clue I needed. It took a bit more to figure out how to deal with variable ASC|DESC. `q =  sql.SQL("select id, {col_name} from some_table order by (CASE when {direction} = 'asc' then {order_field} end) ASC, (CASE when {direction} = 'desc' then {order_field} end) DESC limit {limit_num}").format(col_name=sql.Identifier('name'), order_field=sql.Identifier('id' ), limit_num=sql.Literal(10), direction=sql.Literal('asc'))`